# Obtaining 12 month ahead in sample RMSEs

Tags: forecasting, vector-autoregression, rms

I am attempting to recreate the results of the paper written by King, Stock and Watson in 1995: Temporal instability in the unemployment inflation relationship.

The paper estimates a VAR model with 12 lags using data on inflation and unemployment. They mention that they obtain in sample RMSEs for forecasts at the 6, 12 and 24 month horizon. How is this possible, as I was under the impression that in sample forecasts can be made only when calculating one step ahead forecasts?

Comment: If we would only be able to make one-step-ahead forecasts, they would be rather useless for most use cases.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your help. Would I be able to make in-sample forecasts at the 6, 12, 24 month horizon using a VAR model with 12 lags then? Apologies if this is a very basic question, I am new to time series forecasting.